# How to make crumbly cookies?

Tags: baking, cookies

I am trying to make *alfajores*, following [this](http://southamericanfood.about.com/od/snacksstreetfood/r/alfajorpe.htm) recipe. What steps should I take to make them more crumbly?

Comment: What is your recipe?

Comment: I believe alfajores are quite different from country to country, so I don't think anyone can even hope to answer without you posting your recipe.

Comment: Describe what you mean by crumbly? Would you like the cookie to break up into pieces when you bite it OR would you like it be very flaky so you could scratch it and leave a pile of dust?

Comment: The former; it should offer little resistance when bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to minimize gluten formation, like in making pastry. So, use a low-gluten (pastry) flour. That recipe uses cornstarch alongside flour, which makes sense. You also want to, as much as possible, minimize water and coat the starch granules with fat. So, you might try spinning the flour and fat in a food processor before mixing in the wet ingredients. Definitely use the brandy -- same idea as vodka in a pie crust which helps to prevent gluten formation!